# How does emacs open a file at the same line as the last time it was opened?

Tags: linux, emacs

On my system, if I open a file with `emacs`, scroll down the file and close it, the next time I open the file, `emacs` will automagically scroll down to the same position. How does this work?

Is `emacs` keeping a database somewhere with the last N files I opened and the last cursor position in them? If so, where is this database? How much space would it occupy? Can I control this behavior?

Specs:
Linux Mint Debian Edition
Kernel: 3.2.0-4-amd64
GNU Emacs 23.4.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The database is normally saved in `~/.emacs.d/saveplace`.

This feature is customized in group "Save place" (<kbd>M-x customize group RET save-place RET</kbd>).

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about that. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! On my system it is actually saved in `~/.emacs-places` but the principle is the same, thanks.